# “They are mostly female.”

Tags: prepositional-phrases

There are people. Eight of them are female, and two of them are male. I saw the dictionary express it as they are mostly female. But I want to use any prepositional phrase instead of “mostly.” In this situation, what should I say?

For example, I guess, “they are female for the most number.”

Comment: You could say *The majority of them are female.*

Comment: Why do you want to use a prepositional phrase specifically?

Comment: Ten people - most of them women...

Comment: @Helix Quar Sometimes, we just want to.

Comment: @Kate Bunting What about this? 10 people are female without 2 people?

Comment: That is not idiomatic English. You could say "Ten people, _all but two of them women_". (It sounds odd to talk about 'female people'.)

Comment: @Kate Bunting Is it appositive? “Ten people, all but two of them, are women.”

Comment: I didn't put a second comma in my version. _All but two of them women_ is an appositive phrase describing the ten people.

Comment: @Kate Bunting All but two of them indicates 8 women but how can it describe 10 people?

Comment: @Kate Bunting I mean, how can it be an apposition whose referent is the same with the former’s.

Comment: The idiomatic way to phrase your last sentence is "They are female [for the most **part**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/for-the-most-part)."

Comment: _All but two of them women_ defines the makeup of the group of ten. It was you who raised the subject of appositives, and it seemed to me that this was one.

Comment: @stangdon "They are female for the most part" makes it sound like everyone of them is part-female, part-something else. Mermaids, perhaps. "Most of them are women" or "They are women for the most of them" seems more appropriate here.

Comment: @Stef I disagree with you about it sounding like every one of them is part-female; *for the most part* is frequently used to mean "most of the members of group": consider ["The photographs obtained in this way are for the most part of very good quality."](https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Conway_Library_the_Courtauld_Institu/CJMzAQAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22are+for+the+most+part%22&dq=%22are+for+the+most+part%22&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: @stangdon Of course, you are free to deliberately use ambiguous language, and hope that context will clear the ambiguity for you. Lots of people do that every day, and in some occasions, it even works as intended.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that since "female" is an adjective, some uses of the quantifier seem to distribute the quality partly over each person, rather than partly over the membership of the group. You can make it much clearer and have more options by using the noun "women".

> There are ten people, most of them women.

> There are ten people. Most of them are women.

> There are ten people, mostly women.

> There are ten people, most being women.

Et cetera.